# Request for User Interested tags

Tags: feature-request

Some sites, like linked in, allow you to say "I'm interested in being contacted about ..." with several options.

I've noticed a few people self promote themselves in the body of their answer.  While I find nothing explicitly wrong with that, it might be advantageous to everyone if we had a few User Interested tags.

For example, a user could say, "I'm interested in being contacted about:"
Contract Opportunities,
Full Time Employment,
etc.

This could be indicated with some sort of little badge under their name, and next to their icon.

Comment: I smell social networking... ;)

Comment: @Troggy: why yes, yes you do.  What better place to network than through a knowledge sharing site?

Answer (score 3):

There is not currently a way to "message" another user, so this alone would not add anything. Additionally, SO is not designed to be a social, or even professional, networking site. Over time I would expect that more features related to employment opportunities will be added, but the primary focus will remain Q and A.

Answer (score 2):

Given how little information is typically available on an SO profile, I can't imagine too many quality leads coming through this mechanism. It would be mostly head hunters just spamming the whole site.

Some users post links to their blog or other page where they have more information (including contact info). If an employer is really interested, they can go through that channel instead. And if an SO user wants to be found, he or she will have an appropriate link on their profile.